# How to set a transfer function with a variable coefficient in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, transfer-function

I have a transfer function with a coefficient in the denominator which value changes with the output of the model.
So the question is: How to set a transfer function in simulink with variable coefficients?

It should be done with the block [`transfer fcn Direct Form II Time varying`](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcndirectformiitimevarying.html).
Can anyone explain to me how it works? There is not enough informations concerning this block in the Matlab Documentation! An example would be very helpful .. Thanks

Comment: I tried it with a simple example where I added as inputs: 
`u --> sine signal --
num --> [1 2] --
den --> [x 4] --`
where x is a variable

Comment: What didn't work?  What was the error?  Show us your model.